# Memcached CAS keys not being replicated properly on both the servers

Tags: memcached

we are using two  Memcached servers clusterted (Master , Master  ) and used repcached on top of it for replication purpose ,  for our heavy traffic website

For all logged in users , I am doing a atomic  Memcached cas Operation as shown below .

```
long casVal = resp.getCas();
MemcacheClinet.cas(TOTAL_USERS, 0,value, casVal);
```

After doing some research using Memcache Stats Commands on both the servers  using get TOTAL_USERS , i found that this key has got a different value on each server and its not being replicated properly and its behaving abnormally

Please let me know if is it possible to get this key "TOTAL_USERS" replicated properly on both the servers ??

Or is there any other way where  i can manually append the Data to this String ??

I am uisng XMemcached 1.4.5 version  with repcached 2.2 installed on to it .

Please share your ideas .